# How to display continous line chart (via Zing Chart) with skipped values?

Tags: javascript, visualization, zingchart

I'm using a line chart to display two series of data. Each series could have skipped values(they initialized with null values). In the result I got a line with breaks. The problem is how to display a continious line in case of skipped values (lower chart on image).
I've searched through all questions tagged with "zingchart", read documentation and examples on zingchart.com" but I couldn't found anything that solves my problem.
Here is the image of two charts (upper - what I get, lower - what I need): https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyX5I.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT** - Updated based off comment

In that case, you'd switch from a one dimensional array to a two dimensional array like this:

```
values = [
  [X, Y]
]
```

where X corresponds so the X scale value and Y corresponds to the Y scale value.

Here's a demo: http://demos.zingchart.com/view/R93HI801

You can read more about our data values here: http://www.zingchart.com/docs/reference/data-format-by-chart-type/

I'm on the ZingChart team. Let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: Patrick, as I've pointed out in the question I have already initialized some values with null. The problem in this case I get breaked line chart in places where values are null. But I need continious line chart. Please, see the image link from the question. Is it possible for ZingChart to display continious line for points which have null values?

Comment: Sorry Dimitriy, I misunderstood. In that case, your values array would be an array of arrays like this: `[ [1,1], [3,2], [4,3], [7,9] ]` where the 0th index of each subarray is the X coordinate and the 1st index of each subarray is the Y coordinate. Here's another demo: http://demos.zingchart.com/view/R93HI801

Comment: @Dimitriy - No problem! If the solution answers your question, please accept it so others can see it.